# Hide steps, Jenkins, Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to hide a build step in jenkins pipeline?
I use shared library I would like to hide (hide==it will not present on the GUI) some steps when these is not needed

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

First off, I presume you are trying to hide a `Stage`, not a `Step`?

If so, it is not possible to completely hide it, simply because some builds might have the stage turned on, and some might not - therefore the stage should always be there, but empty(disabled) when excluded from the build.

You need to put `when { expression { return ... } }` at the beginning of your stage and return any expression that evaluates to `true` or `false` depending on if you want the stage to run or not.
Example code:

```
stage('My Test Stage') {
  when {
    expression {return <TRUE OR FALSE HERE>}
  }
         
  steps {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

It is not necessarily has to be a stage, step would be enough for me. 
Currently, I use this syntax,

`stage('Hide stage') {when { beforeInput true allOf{expression { currentBuild.result != 'ABORTED' && VERSION != 'false' }}`

The main problem is: 
Every developer can see these stages.
So I would like to hide them, and these have to be visible only if the conditions are the match.

Answer (score 0):

Solution (workaround):

```
     stage('Steps for hide') {
      steps {
        script {
          if ( conditions == "true" ) {
                  echo "steps 1"
            }
          else if ( conditions == "false" ){
                  echo "steps 2"
          }
          else if ( conditions == "null" ) {
                  echo "No conditions step required."
          }
        }
      }
    }
```